# Using Picture-in-picture feature with Android mobile (and not Android TV)

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

In the new Android 7.0 android released a new feature of [Picture-in-picture](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/picture-in-picture.html). As mentioned in the documentation:

> **Android TV** users can now watch a video in a pinned window in a corner of the screen when navigating within or between apps.

I want to develop an android mobile app, that will play videos, and i want to enable the app users to minimized the video and continue to use my app - exactly what the Picture-in-picture feature enables in **Android TV**.

**My question:** can i create an [android TV project](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html), and support the Picture-in-picture feature in and android **mobile** device running android 7.0?

Comment: Did u find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The 1st Android version supporting PIP is 8.0.